# Dynamically adding View items in horizontalscrollview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I have Horizontal scroll view inside Listview.
What I want is to dynamically add ViewItem in the row horizontally scrolled.
In my application 10 stories are fetched from API at once, when user scolls next 10 will be displayed and the no. os stories can be infinte. So i can not fix view items in xml.
Also i need to implement onclick listener on each viewitem. Any Idea how to do it ??

**CutomAdapter Class**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<String> data;
private ArrayList<String> image;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

private Context context;
public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> d, ArrayList<String> i) 
{
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    image=i;
    inflater (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    context=(Context)activity.getBaseContext();
        }

public int getCount() 
{
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{

    TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5,tv6,tv7,tv8,tv9,tv10;

    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    tv1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    tv2=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    tv3=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
    tv4=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    tv5=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    tv6=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv7=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    tv8=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    tv9=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    tv10=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textView5);


    tv1.setText(data.get(position).toString());
    tv2.setText(data.get(position).toString());
    tv3.setText(data.get(position).toString());
    tv4.setText(data.get(position).toString());
    tv5.setText(data.get(position).toString());
    tv6.setText(image.get(position).toString());
    tv7.setText(image.get(position).toString());
    tv8.setText(image.get(position).toString());
    tv9.setText(image.get(position).toString());
    tv10.setText(image.get(position).toString());

    return vi;
}
```

}

**list_row.xml** Row of listview

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text 1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text 1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text 1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text 1" />
            </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text 1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text 1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text 1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text 1" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text 1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Text 1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>


</LinearLayout
```

>

**What I want is to dynamically add items into horizontal scroll view as it is scrolled**
As The stories can be infinte, but my API will provide 10 stories at a time.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried inflating new Linear layout but was unable it include it in my custom adapter as it was extending BaseAdapter. And i require Activity to be extended to inflate it.

Comment: @IHawk : have added my code.

Answer (score 0):

Create an Adapter.
In the adapter you can create a view for every image, text or whatever you want.
There are plenty of examples on the internet. 
[This](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters) for example.

Then to refresh every time you scroll for example.
You can use    `notifyDataSetChanged()` in the adapter to refresh.

Also, [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&t) is a great video on listviews at Google I/O